# How to get current workspace in macOS 10.13?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-high-sierra

I want to get the current workspace in my app. I found a way to achieve my goal from [valexa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547103/change-the-wallpaper-on-all-desktops-in-os-x-10-7-lion/9514471#9514471):

```
-(int)spaceNumber
{
    CFArrayRef windowsInSpace = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionAll | kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);      
    for (NSMutableDictionary *thisWindow in (NSArray *)windowsInSpace)    {
        if ([thisWindow objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowWorkspace]){
            return [[thisWindow objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowWorkspace] intValue];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But now(macOS 10.13.3 for my case) the [kCGWindowWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgwindowworkspace)  is not existed any more. So are there any other ways to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub utility WhichSpace [github.com/gechr/WhichSpace] will put a numeric icon in the toolbar, indicating which Desktop number is the current Space. This can be queried with Applescript:

```
tell application "System Events" ¬
  to tell process "WhichSpace" ¬
    to set temp to (title of menu bar items of menu bar 1)
return item 1 of temp
```

The following Swift code will call a function when the Desktop changes. That's also potentially useful.

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: 
  NSWorkspace.activeSpaceDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil,
    using: <the function you want to handle this event> )
```